# Proving a linear map to be injective and/or surjective

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

So the linear map I'm talking about is defined as follows:

$l_1: P_1(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2, l_1(p):= \begin{pmatrix}\int_{0}^{1} p(x) dx\\2p(1) \end{pmatrix}$

My approach is this:

For injectivity:

Let $p,q \in P_1(\mathbb{R})\,\, p(x):= ax+b ; \,\, q(x) = cx+d$
Now assume that $l_1(p) = l_1(q)$

Show that this possible if and only if $p = q \Rightarrow a=c \land b=d$

$l_1(p) = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{a}{2}+b\\2a+2b \end{pmatrix}$

$l_1(q) = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{c}{2}+d\\2c+2d \end{pmatrix}$

Because of my assumption from the beginning I can now write:

$\begin{pmatrix}\frac{a}{2}+b\\2a+2b \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{c}{2}+d\\2c+2d \end{pmatrix} $

Two vectors are equal if their components in the same row are equal i.e.:

$\frac{a}{2}+b = \frac{c}{2}+d$ and $2a+2b = 2c+2d$

But now I'm struggling how to show that this means that a = c and b = d and therefore p = q or the opposite that $p \neq q$

Note: 
$P_1(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of all polynomials with degree 1 which take reals as inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You second equation implies $a+b = c+d$, which is equivalent to $\frac{a}{2}+b+\frac{a}{2} = \frac{c}{2}+d+\frac{c}{2}$. By the first equation, this gets you $a = c$ and hence also $b = d$.

By the way, since you have a linear map, it actually suffices to check that only $0$ is mapped to $0$, which would make the computation a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

The spaces have the same dimension, so you just need to prove one of the properties and the other will follow.

For injectivity you need, given $p(x)=ax+b$ with $l_1(p)=0$,
$$
\int_0^1(ax+b)\,dx=\frac{a}{2}+b=0\qquad 2p(1)=2a+2b=0
$$
This easily implies $a=b=0$. Thus the kernel of $l_1$ is $\{0\}$ and you're done.

---

It's not difficult to prove surjectivity as well: given $\begin{pmatrix} s \\ t \end{pmatrix}$ you need to find $a$ and $b$ such that
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a/2+b \\ 2a+2b \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} s \\ t \end{pmatrix}
$$
and this is a linear system.

---

More abstract method: find the matrix of $l_1$ with respect to the basis $\{1,x\}$ and the standard basis on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since
$$
l_1(1)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
l_1(x)=\begin{pmatrix} 1/2 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
the matrix is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1/2 \\
2 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which has rank $2$.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 equations (Note: I didn't check if your previous calculations were right)

$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{a}{2} + b = \frac{c}{2} + d\\
2a+2b = 2c + 2d
\end{cases}$$

Now, multiply the first equation by $2$, and divide the second one by $2$

$$
\begin{cases}
a + 2b = c + 2d\\
a+b = c + d \\
\end{cases}$$

Substract second equation from the first one

$$
\begin{cases}
b = d\\
a+b = c + d \\
\end{cases}$$

Substract again:

$$
\begin{cases}
b = d \\
a = c
\end{cases}$$

And you're done